# Ubuntu отсчитывает секунды в слух. Как это выключить?

Tags: ubuntu

Поставил ubuntu 20 что-то там. И если нет никакого источника воспроизведения звука - он начинает отстукивать каждую секунду, похоже на даблклик мышки. Решить можно только выключением колонок/наушников, либо поставить что-то на, например, ютубе на низкой кромкости.

Подскажите, как эту опцию вырубить?
Уже начинает раздражать, особенно, когда работаешь.

Comment: Блок питания проверить бы) у меня было что щелкало при движении мыши.

Comment: попробуйте советы от опытных убунтуводов https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @PakUula ну так оформите как ответ) В рускоязычном SO не помешает)))

Comment: Да ладно. Я пользуюсь убунтой только в консольном варианте или удалённо через VS Code. В UI ничего не понимаю ))

Comment: @PakUula спасибо, всё сработало! Я добавил перевод инструкции, может кому-то ещё понадобится. Спасибо ещё раз)) Правда теперь у меня у соседей ремонт, но это уже другая история XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не изобретал, спасибо @PakUula за ссылку. Мне помогло. На втором шаге противное тиканье ушло, что не может не радовать :) Витиевато, но вполне осуществимо даже не для специалиста ИТ.
Вот вольный перевод инструкции:

=======================================================

Это произошло из-за того, что Ubuntu включила возможности энергосбережения звуковой карты. Отключение может быть единственным способом избавиться от надоедливого звука:

**1).** Проверьте, как работает параметр `power_save` вашей звуковой карты:

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

**2).** Если возвращается "1", сделайте следующее, чтобы временно изменить его:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

**3).** Если предыдущий шаг сработал для вас, сохраните эту конфигурацию (**иначе проблема сохранится после перезагрузки**):

```
echo "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf
```

**4).** (Необязательно) Вы также можете сделать то же самое для параметра `power_save_controller`, выполнив шаги 1), 2) и 3), заменив `power_save` на `power_save_controller`, также изменив 0 на N.

*Примечание: использование первого шага, вероятно, вернет Y для этого параметра вместо 1.*